# symfony doctrine will not default a boolean to 0

Tags: mysql, symfony, null, doctrine, boolean

I have tried in several ways to have symfony default a boolean to 0 rather than null (as null gives me a database level error upon flush).

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]:
> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'auto_created' cannot be
> null

This made no difference:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":"0"})
 */
private $autoCreated;
```

Some logic i the setter made no difference either

```
public function setAutoCreated(bool $autoCreated): self
{
    if is_null($autoCreated) {
        $autoCreated = 0;
    }

    $this->autoCreated = $autoCreated;

    return $this;
}
```

As well as

```
public function setAutoCreated(bool $autoCreated): self
{
    if is_null($autoCreated) {
        $autoCreated = false;
    }

    $this->autoCreated = $autoCreated;

    return $this;
}
```

Database looks like this

[image: phpmyadmin saying default:0]

I am clearly missing something...?

Sure I can do a simple $user->setAutoCreated(false); everywhere I create this entity, but I don't get why I should have to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of PHP you're using, you should be able to do something like this in your entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $autoCreated = false;
```

Whenever an instance of this class is created, `$autoCreated` will be set to `false`. So when you try to persist the object, it'll have a default value of `false` and Doctrine will set the field to 0.

Alternatively, you can explicitly set `$autoCreated` to `false` in your constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->autoCreated = false;
}
```

Note that you can only use the first approach for simple, built-in PHP types or constants. For more complicated objects (e.g., a Doctrine `ArrayCollection`) you'll need to use the constructor approach.

Comment: The constructor... why didn't I think of that 0=) seeing I use it high and low in my controllers... thx. And naturally, the putting a default in the setter avails nothing as that setter is never called =D